# C# Language Lexer

Tags: c#, language-design, lexical-analysis

Here is a Lexer for a programming language I am working on. Any feedback would be appreciated. I only started learning C# a couple of days ago, so please excuse my newbie code :)

```cs
namespace Sen
{
    enum TokenType
    {
        IDENTIFIER,
        NUMBER,
        STRING,
        SEMICOLON,
        PLUS,
        MINUS,
        STAR,
        SLASH,
    }

    class Token
    {
        public TokenType type;
        public string value;

        public Token(TokenType type, string value  = "")
        {
            this.type = type;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    class Lexer
    {
        public readonly List<Token> tokens;

        private int charIdx;
        private readonly string sourceRaw;

        char CurrentChar
        {
            get { return sourceRaw[charIdx]; }
        }

        public Lexer(string sourceRaw)
        {
            this.sourceRaw = sourceRaw;
            tokens = new List<Token>();
        }

        bool IsEnd
        {
            get { return charIdx >= sourceRaw.Length; }
        }

        char? NextChar()
        {
            try {
                return sourceRaw[charIdx++];
            } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void Lex()
        {
            while (!IsEnd) {
                switch (CurrentChar) {
                    case ';': AddToken(TokenType.SEMICOLON);  break;
                    case ' ': break;
                    case '\'':
                    case '"':
                        LexString();
                        break;
                    case '+': AddToken(TokenType.PLUS); break;
                    case '-': AddToken(TokenType.MINUS); break;
                    case '*': AddToken(TokenType.STAR); break;
                    case '/': AddToken(TokenType.SLASH); break;
                    default:
                        if (char.IsLetter(CurrentChar)) {
                            LexIdentifier();
                            continue;
                        } else if (char.IsNumber(CurrentChar)) {
                            LexNumber();
                            continue;
                        }

                        throw new UnexpectedCharacterException(CurrentChar);
                }

                NextChar();
            }
        }

        void AddToken(TokenType type, string value = "")
        {
            tokens.Add(new Token(type, value));
        }

        void LexIdentifier()
        {
            int startIdx = charIdx;
            int endIdx = startIdx;

            while (!IsEnd && CurrentChar != ' ' && CurrentChar != ';') {
                if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(CurrentChar) && CurrentChar != '_')
                    throw new UnexpectedCharacterException(CurrentChar);

                NextChar();
                endIdx++;
            }

            string value = sourceRaw[startIdx..endIdx];
            AddToken(TokenType.IDENTIFIER, value);
        }
        
        void LexNumber()
        {
            int startIdx = charIdx;
            int endIdx = startIdx;

            while (!IsEnd && CurrentChar != ' ' && CurrentChar != ';' && char.IsNumber(CurrentChar)) {
                NextChar();
                endIdx++;
            }

            string value = sourceRaw[startIdx..endIdx];
            AddToken(TokenType.NUMBER, value);
        }

        void LexString()
        {
            char opening = CurrentChar;
            int startIdx = charIdx + 1;
            int endIdx = startIdx - 1;

            NextChar();

            while (CurrentChar != opening) {
                if (IsEnd)
                    throw new ExpectedCharacterException(opening);

                NextChar();
                endIdx++;
            }

            string value = sourceRaw[startIdx..endIdx];
            AddToken(TokenType.STRING, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to CR and to C#.  First thing first, you should become familiar with [C# Naming Conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions).  A few that I choose to emphasize in regards to your post:

In `Token` class, the fields `type` and `value` should become **properties** named `Type` and `Value`.  In general, fields are private unless they are constant or static.  If you wish to expose a field as public, then it should be a property instead.  Also, properties and methods should be named with Pascal casing.

Though not required, I personally prefer to decorate all properties, fields, and method with its access modifier, even if it is private.  Granted, private is the default but I want to make sure that a beginner has given it thought and explicitly marked it so.

Regarding braces, there are 2 areas for improvement.  One, the current thinkng with C# is that the open and close braces occur on their own line.  And two, one-liners are frowned upon and should encorporate braces.

Taking that into consideration, this would be a rewrite of one method:

```
private char? NextChar()
{
    try
    {
        return sourceRaw[charIdx++];
    } 
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Except that entire method can use a less expensive `if` rather than a `try-catch` block.

```
private char? NextChar() => (charIdx >= 0 && !IsEnd) 
                          ? sourceRaw[charIdx++] 
                          : null;
```

Why both to catch an exception if all you is ignore it?  Especially when there is simple code that can easily work around it.

Back to braces, lines such as:

```
if (IsEnd)
    throw new ExpectedCharacterException(opening);
```

should be converted to:

```
if (IsEnd)
{
    throw new ExpectedCharacterException(opening);
}
```

There are a few properties or methods where you may consider using `=>`.  Example:

```
private bool IsEnd => charIdx >= sourceRaw.Length;
```

You seem to use `CurrentChar != ' ' && CurrentChar != ';'` frequently.  Apparently, these are delimiters between tokens and values.  The DRY Principle (Don't Repeat Yourself) suggests this could become its own property:

```
private bool IsDelimiter => CurrentChar == ' ' || CurrentChar == ';'
```

Elsewhere in code you would replace `CurrentChar != ' ' && CurrentChar != ';'` with `!IsDelimiter`.  The advantage here, besides readability, is that if you were ever to add a 3rd delimiter in the future, you would only have to change it in one spot.